# Dropdown and Menu container with overflow not working well

Tags: css, reactjs, dropdown

I created react component for dropdown which is working as expected.
The problem is when I try to build navbar with 100vw width and overflow x auto , the dropdown loose his absolute property and it seems the menu height is scrollable by y direction.

```
//dropdown.tsx
const Dropdown: React.FC<DropdownProps> = ({ items, title, variant = "primary", border = false }) => {
  const { theme } = useToken();
  return (
    <div className={`dropdown`}>
      <div className={`dropdown-toggle ${theme} ${variant} ${border ? " ui-border" : ""}`}>{title}</div>

      <ul className={`dropdown-menu ${variant} ${theme}`}>
        {items.map((item, index) => {
          if (!item) return null;
          return (
            <li key={index} className={`dropdown-item ${variant} ${theme}`}>
              {item}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```
///dropdown.css
/* Dropdown.css */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-secondary);
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: var(--spacing-sm);
  animation: dd-pops ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

.dropdown-menu.primary {
  background-color: var(--light-secondary-color);
  color: var(--font-color);
}
.dropdown-menu.secondary {
  background-color: var(--dark-secondary-color);
  color: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-item {
  padding: var(--spacing-sm);
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-item.primary:hover {
  background-color: var(--bg-secondary-color);
}
```

till here the dropdown works very fine !

but now i try to create menu component and the problem is when it scrollable

```
const NavBarSecondary = () => {
  

 

  const drawDepartments = () => {
    return departments.map((dep, idx) => {
      const title = <div >{dep.title}</div>
      const subCategories = dep.subCategories.map((cat: any) => {
        return (
          <Link key={cat.id} to={`/products/${cat.key}`}>
            <li>{cat[language]}</li>
          </Link>
        );
      });
      return <Dropdown items={subCategories} title={title} >;
    });
  };

  return <nav className={`categories-flex-nav`}>{drawDepartments()}</nav>;
};
```

and the last class of categories-flex-nav

```
.categories-flex-nav {
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x:auto
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```